# How to set active a button in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I have a code in xslt for selecting two values using buttons.I need to check the value and set active the corresponding button.here is my code

```
 <ul class="switch">
 <li class="private-btn">
 <xsl:if test="library:RequestQueryString('at') = 'privat'">

here i need the active btn code

 </xsl:if>
 <input type="button" class="Privat" value="Privat"></input>

 </li>
 <li class="business-btn">
 <xsl:if test="library:RequestQueryString('at') = 'Erhverv'">

   here i need the active btn code

</xsl:if>
<input type="button" class="Privat" value="Erhverv"></input>
 </li>
</ul>
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to conditionally set the `disabled` html attribute (and possibly other attributes) on the button.

You can conditionally add the attribute like so:

```
<input type="button" class="Privat" value="Erhverv">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="library:RequestQueryString('at') = 'privat'">
      <xsl:attribute name="disabled">disabled</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      ... Other attribute here etc.
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</input>
```

Since it seems you need to reuse the logic, you can also refactor the enabled / attribute state generation into a call template, like so:

```
  <xsl:template name="SetActiveState">
    <xsl:param name="state"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$state='true'">
        <xsl:attribute name="disabled">disabled</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>...</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

And then call it like so:

```
<input type="button" class="Privat" value="Erhverv">
  <xsl:call-template name="SetActiveState">
    <xsl:with-param name="state" 
                    select="library:RequestQueryString('at') = 'privat'">
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</input>
```

... same for `<input type="button" class="Privat" value="Privat"></input>`